# Detect Browsers older than two years

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, browser

This is for a private company site with about 10,000 users.

I've seen a couple of efforts for browser detection but nothing with the age of the browser, does anyone have an idea for this?

Related Projects:

- http://fresh-browsers.com/en
- https://github.com/Groozly/Fresh-Browsers
- http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/

So far I was thinking client side but if there are any server side options I'm open to that as well.

not looking to scrape sites.

They are looking to upgrade browsers and currently want to drop support for browsers older than two year

Comment: If they have any Windows XP systems, it'll be a bit of a trick. IE8 is the latest version of IE for Windows XP, and it's more than two years old.

Comment: yes but I can steer them to another browser option such as Chrome or FireFox if that's the case

Comment: @PhillPafford You can't expect people to shuffle from device to device, browser to browser, in order to consume your content. Build something that works on all. That doesn't mean it has to work the same on all, but don't alienate customers who may be on a slightly aged device/browser.

Comment: @JonathanSampson it's an internal site for employees only but there are multiple site around the globe, also there is a level of access (Like manager/employee relationship) so communication is limited as well. I'm looking for a solution to upgrade end users browsers without the need to communicate this to a mass audience.

Comment: @PhillPafford Instructing all employees to upgrade their browser probably should be an administrative task.

Comment: @JonathanSampson agreed but it's not that simple

Comment: @PhillPafford I'm trying to make it simpler for you though. Filtering user agent strings is not making things easier on you, it actually makes it harder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're going about it all the wrong way. You don't support browsers,  you support features. Browsers don't expire like a can of beans would in your pantry. Use feature detection and polyfills when developing - this will retroactively provide support to browsers 10 years old.

Various tools exist to help you support browsers that may be lacking in the feature department. One popular one is Modernizr. Not only does this expose an object that tells you over 40 different things about what the user agent is capable of, it also polyfills a subset of HTML5 tags, and attaches informative CSS classnames to your document that let you style against browsers that support or don't support any given feature.

Using great practices like this will ultimately result in a better experience for your clients, improved reputation for your employer, and less frustration for you having to try and figure out some magical expression for determining the antiquity of a faceless browser by some mutable user agent string.

Comment: hmm but wouldn't the list of features be as long (or longer) then a list of user agents?

Comment: @PhillPafford Features are reliable, user agent strings are not.

Comment: You only detect the features that you need.

Comment: Rant: feature detection needs to be used consistently only because browser detection is bad.  If browser detection weren't bad, it would be better to use maybe about 50% of the time.  Sometimes it is nice to say "X feature is not supported, here are alternatives:" and change styles, but sometimes you would ideally want to give the user a much friendlier message (especially non-technical users): "You are using IE7.  This website won't work.  Here are some links to upgrage."

Comment: @tandu It's far better to say "Sorry, this feature of our site is unavailable to you and we were unable to provide a fallback" than to say "Sorry, there was a board missing from your bridge, so we burned the whole thing down. Get a new bridge."

Comment: @JonathanSampson sometimes that is true, but sometimes you may have a user base that has no idea what X feature is or why they should care.

Comment: @tandu Feature detection doesn't require anybody to know about features. It requires developers to know how to respond when something is unavailable. If the best reaction is to encourage a browser download (when the feature is crucial), so be it. But that should be Plan B, not the a knee-jerk reaction.

Comment: @JonathanSampson you say so, but I would rather be told what browsers the site will work on than be told it doesn't work and have to hunt for one that does.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I know of http://modernizr.com/ but is there anything you would recommend?

Comment: @PhillPafford Code against the Modernizr object, style against the Modernizr classes, and polyfill when necessary. You can find a great assortment of polyfills online at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox includes a build date in it's User Agent string, but I'm not sure if other browsers do that. I think your best bet will be to use a white list approach rather than trying to black list an unknown number of browsers. Here are a few sites that can help you warn users when their browser isn't on your white list.

- http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/
- http://browser-update.org/
- http://www.ajaxblender.com/browser-detection.html
- http://www.updateyourbrowser.net/en/
- http://www.privacychoice.org/resources/browser_upgrade
  -

Comment: That said, @Jonathon Sampson's suggestion to use feature detection and polyfills is probably a more robust solution.