# My Site not opening in IE

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer

My Site  is not opening in IE. I know about CSS incompatibilities this is why I added the following code to redirect to a static page if UserAgent belongs to Internet Explorer. The code that detects IE and redirects is given below:

Site link is:

http://adnansiddiqi.com/main.html

http://pastebin.com/MCRbsrmi

The header file is included on top of the main.php

Please guide!

Comment: If you fixed the validation errors then you may not have to redirect to an IE version, fix the problem not cover it up, http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://adnansiddiqi.com/main.html

Comment: IE developer toolbar might be a good help for you to debug.

Comment: @Volatil3 Do you have short-tags enabled in PHP?

Comment: code of the accessed file is given here http://pastebin.com/Y4YxudmK the code of header.php is here: http://pastebin.com/MCRbsrmi

Comment: Can **defer** could be the issue?

Comment: @Volatil3 No, it's not the cause of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've got the site working properly, we finally have an error message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/adnansid/public_html/main.php:10) in /home/adnansid/public_html/header.php on line 15

See item 6 from the list below. Don't call `header()` after you've already sent output. You must call it before any and all output.

---

Here are a series of things you need to fix/address/attempt:

1. Two undefined variables, `isMobileSafari`, and `isOldMobileSafari`.
2. Your `<title>` needs to be within your `<head>`.
3. No doctype was provided.
4. You're not outputting anything after the opening `<body>` tag.
5. Check to make sure you have short-tags enabled (try using the longform `<?php ... ?>`)
6. **Don't call `header()` after you've already output content.**
7. Check your log files for any obvious messages.

I tried accessing the same page in Chrome, thinking maybe you had broken your user-agent sniffing code, but I found that within Chrome as well nothing is output after the opening `<body>` tag.

I would try to diagnose the reason why your body isn't being output, but you've not provided enough code for us to do that. Please provide us a bit more to further assist you.

The quick solution is to avoid user-agent sniffing code, and instead [detect features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354577/detect-browsers-older-than-two-years/10354618#10354618).

Comment: Let me try to put data i JSFiddle

Comment: @Volatil3 Just post your data here. The entire page, with your PHP functions and all.

Comment: This is the URL   http://jsfiddle.net/RGL7a/21/  The left HTML section has the sniffin code and respective JS file   This fiddle will not run  properly, all I put the respective header.php code and respective JS content

Comment: @Volatil3 What is this? How does it relate to the code you posted here in your question? Don't separate  your code - in doing so you are making it near impossible for us to answer the question for you. Show us the code, as it appears, in your text editor.

Comment: I am using separate files for JS and header.php

Comment: @Volatil3 You shouldn't be calling `header()` after you've already output HTML. Move that code up before all of your HTML.

Comment: you mean sniffing on the top? I wonder why it did not throw error on Chrome? wait let me enable debug mode

Comment: @Volatil3 No error in Chrome because `header()` is never called for the Chrome user.

Comment: @Volatil3 And now it's working. Next, you need to abandon all of it and actually support Internet Explorer :)

Comment: Jonathan What do you see? :) noie.html?

Comment: @Volatil3 I do see it, from Internet Explorer 10, which is standards compliant and capable of handling all that you throw at it. Which means you've killed a perfectly good opportunity for me to browse your site :)

Comment: Actually, I am on Mac and this is more my personal profile than anything else. Since its related to Technical thing so I assume that techies would have more than 1 browser plus I want the world to use something good :D. I cant check things on IE as I am a Mac user and I am too lazy to make it IE compliant. Since you say IE10 is compliant so I can add a version restriction it. In future I am gonna opensource this code on GitHub

Comment: I am adding up IE10 string in it. Right now I am asking my lil sis to borrow her machine for testing, it has IE8 installed on XP

Comment: Thanks a ton, I saw on IE8 and it redirected as expected. Love you man!

Answer (score 1):

i think a `JavaScript` error is thrown

```
da1a2063-40eb-4efd-ae4b-c50a8eea8067.js, line 7 character 117
```

may be this script does not support IE , Did you use any **API** ? .. may be a workaround or a fix is available

Comment: Yes it is not suppose to open on IE and it should redirect to http://adnansiddiqi.com/noie.html page. I am not using any such API. I need to test again

Comment: I know IE is bad but totally removing it from your website? Thats a low blow for old people everywhere!

Comment: @Sam its more a personal site related to technical stuff then a general site, It has more details regarding my CV and things I do than anything some non-techie would like plus I want them to use something better :)